# Data structure vocabulary about trees

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, vocabulary

What adjectives are used to characterize the following 3 data structures :

- a k-ary tree where all nodes have exaclty `0` or `k` children ?
- a tree where all leaves are at the same level ?
- a tree where only leaves contain data ("empty" internal nodes) ?

I am searching for widespread and well-established adjectives whose every one in graph theory will understand.

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this can not be done let say that we have 3-ary tree, when you put the first element the first rule is broken, so you do not have 3 children. 
 also can be proven that thing what you want  is not possible